What is the name of this motor?
I was looking for a motor which can push a rod at speed (not like linear actutator), but could not find the name of it hence no idea how to search and buy it. It looks like https://www.youtube.com/shorts/csFAsy0_3E8
In this short two motors are shown, I want to know the name of first motor, which is pushing a rod at fast speed and then it comes back.

Unfortunately, this is specifically the home improvement stack, so unless you're using this to automate part of your home it's offtopic.

We call that device a Solenoid, not motor
The model you are shoving is from China (with Chinese writing), and I can not tell you what it is.
Here is a example of Solenoid

found on 

Stack Exchange policies require that images which are not the creative work of the poster be properly attributed via a link to where the image was found. Please update your posting to bring this into compliance.
